# About git --amend -m "blablalba"

Tags: git

I want to modify my last committed and pushed message. 
After I did `git --amend -m "blahblah"`
should I `git push` again?
Do i need `-f` or anything?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to modified published history.  By published history we mean commits that have been pushed upstream.

Nevertheless, if you **MUST** do so, I find the best approach to delete the upstream branch and then re-push your local branch out.

```
git push origin :<branch-name>
git push -u origin <branch-name>
```

(change origin if your remote is named otherwise)

After doing so, you must take care to communicate to fellow collaboraters.  They will want to reset their local branches to the remote branch after fetching down the latest changes

```
git fetch origin
git reset <branch-name> origin/<branch-name>
```

NOTE: the above will make them lose any commits they haven't pushed up stream or merged into other branches.

Answer (score 2):

If you already pushed the commit, don't `--amend` unless you know for sure that nobody else has pulled from it already. If you know that, you'll need to do `git push -f` to get the changes public.

Really, don't do non fast-forward modifications (rebase, --amend) if you already pushed it. It will result in problems down the road.